# I am a New Zealand Passport holder do I need a visa to visit Palau

Tags: visas, paperwork, visa-free-entry, new-zealand-citizens

I am a New Zealand passport holder. Do I need a visa for Palau? I am transiting through Seoul and Taiwan. Do I need visa for those countries as well?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

**South Korea**

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of New Zealand for a
>   maximum stay of 90 days

**Taiwan**

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of New Zealand for amaximum of 90 days

**Palau**

> Visa Issuance:
>   Visa required, **except** for Nationals of New Zealand can obtain
>   a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 30 days. They can
>   apply to extend their stay.